# C++ variable declaration is treated like a function declaration

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The question is fairly theoretical, though it's interesting what makes MS VS2010 treat the following variable declaration (inside `main`) like a function declaration:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<asymm::PrivateKey> PrivateKeyPtr;

...
void main()
{
    ...
    maidsafe::dht::PrivateKeyPtr pk(); // I'm trying to init variable here, though it thinks it's function declaration

    kNode->node()->Store(key, value, "", ttl, pk, std::bind(&StoreCallback, args::_1, key, ttl));
}
```

It throws the following exception:

```
Error   5   error C2664: 'maidsafe::dht::Node::Store' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'maidsafe::dht::PrivateKeyPtr (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'maidsafe::dht::PrivateKeyPtr'  C:\Projects\MaidSafe-DHT\src\maidsafe\dht\demo\demo_main.cc 286 1   KademliaDemo
```

While the following lines work like a charm:

```
maidsafe::dht::PrivateKeyPtr pk = maidsafe::dht::PrivateKeyPtr();

kNode->node()->Store(key, value, "", ttl, pk, std::bind(&StoreCallback, args::_1, key, ttl));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare it without the `()`:

```
maidsafe::dht::PrivateKeyPtr pk;
```

Unfortunately, for primitive types that gives you an uninitialized value, but in C++11 you can value initialize with `{}`:

```
maidsafe::dht::PrivateKeyPtr pk{};
```

For a related parsing issue, see the [c++ most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).